# Converting from Binary to Decimal python function

Tags: python, while-loop, binary, decimal

I'm having trouble with two different functions i have for converting a decimal number into a binary number. I want the binary number to return in the form of a list with commas inbetween each digit. i.e >>>Binary(19) returns [1,0,0,1,1]
My first function says 'int too large to convert to float' and the second function returns the binary number in  a string not a list with commas, and im having difficulty changing that around.
The first function:

```
    def Binary(n):
    i=1
    s=0
    while n>0:
        rem=n%2
        s=s+(i*rem)
        n=n/2
        i=i*10
    return s
```

My second function that returns a string:

```
    def Binary2(n):
        binstr = ''
        if n == 0: return '0'
        while n > 0:
           binstr = str(n % 2) + binstr
           n = n >> 1
        return binstr
```

I only need just one function to output the result im looking for, so i appreciate any help thanks:)

Also i know there is many easier ways of doing this but i prefer to stick to using the while loop

Comment: please indent your code properly :)

Comment: whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
def binary(n):
    binlist = [int(x) for x in bin(n)[2:]]
    return binlist
```

If you really want to use a `while` loop:

```
def binary(n):
    binary = list()
    while n > 0:
        binary.insert(0, n%2)
        n /= 2

    return binary
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you expect to get a `list` if you are never creating one?

You should first, initialize your return value to an empty list `[]`.
And then use `append` (to add each new item at the end), or `insert` (to add it to the beginning).